# GTM - Implementing DataLayer with VirtualURL and Standard ECommerce

Tags: google-analytics

I need some advice what is the right approach for converting my existing GA into GTM. I have a simple Single Page Application via Ajax, customer will shop, make payment and receive a thankyou page.

```
Shop > Pay > Thankyou
```

I've setup 1 goal in GA, with 3 virtual URLs to track the funnel. On Thankyou page, I will collect sales data and pass to GA via Standard Ecommerce.

On the GTM side, I've created a Universal Analytics tag, with standard Ecommerce configured. The tag will fire when detects the VirtualPageview event in the dataLayer, collect the virtualPageURL and pass back to GA(UA). Ecommerce sales also sharing the same event in the Datalayer.

**Shop**

```
dataLayer.push({'event':'VirtualPageview', 'virtualPageURL':'/Shop.html'});
```

**Pay**

```
dataLayer.push({'event':'VirtualPageview', 'virtualPageURL':'/Pay.html'});
```

**Thankyou - With Standard Ecommerce details**

```
dataLayer.push({
'event':'VirtualPageview', 
'virtualPageURL':'/Thankyou.html',
'transactionId': ID,
'transactionAffiliation': '',
'transactionTotal': PRICE ,
'transactionProducts': [
{
  sku: '',
  name: '',
  category: '',
  price: '',
  quantity: 1   
}]
});
```

Currently I can see the Virtual page is tracking correctly. However, I do not see any Ecommerce or transactions data in my GA. Assuming my ECommerce is passing the data correctly, do I just need one tag to collect the VirtualPageView and Ecommerce? Or do I require additional tag for the ECommerce.

For your information, my GTM is declared above the page, I will need an event to trigger the datalayer capturing.

Comment: Hey men, in standart ecommerce is mandatory to create a tag for ecommerce, have you created it?, if yes, please share a screenshot of it because there must be the issue.(hide sensitive data :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard E-Commerce requires that you have a GA type with track type "Transaction" on your confirmation page.

[image]

Comment: This means I will have a page view tag and a transaction tag?